# How to extract pixel values from raster?

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I have created a grid using fishnet which has cells that are equal to 10 m (with and height) and the grid size is 2.24 x 2.24 km.
Using this grid I would like to extract all band values from the raster. How can I speed up the extraction?

Currently, I tried:

```
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS public.band_value_1_whole_km;
CREATE TABLE public.band_value_1_whole_km AS
 SELECT
    g.gid,
    g.geom,
    g.row,
    g.col, 
    st_value(rd.rast, 1, st_centroid(g.geom)) as band_2,
    st_value(rd.rast, 2, st_centroid(g.geom)) as band_3,
    st_value(rd.rast, 3, st_centroid(g.geom)) as band_4,
    st_value(rd.rast, 4, st_centroid(g.geom)) as band_8,
    st_value(rd.rast, 5, st_centroid(g.geom)) as band_11, 
    st_value(rd.rast, 6, st_centroid(g.geom)) as ndvi, 
    st_value(rd.rast, 7, st_centroid(g.geom)) as ndbi
    FROM
    public.grid_for_test_1km_vector g
left jOIN
    public.t32ulc_entire_tile rd 
on 
    st_intersects(rd.rast, g.geom);
```

grid_for_test_1km_vector is grid table that contains polygons, while t32ulc_entire_tile has raster data that has the area which intersects with the grid polygons. This query executes very slowly...

Comment: The query is probably long because the join is made without an index. Check that there is a spatial index on the *geom* and *rast* columns.

Comment: @Atm how can I check? I have created an index with gist for the grid_for_test_1km_vector table, while raster data has rid column by default.

Comment: @Atm I have checked, and they both have spatial indexes: